# syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Hi I'm new To Code Ignitor And i want to know why my code produced this error.

```
function index(){
    $this->load->library('form-validation');
    $this->form-validation-set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
    $this->form-validation-set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
    if ($this->form-validation->run() ==  FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('reg_form_view');//failed input
    } else {
        //redirect('reg_success','refresh');
        echo "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: issue is in form-validation- change it to `form_validation->` in case it not works check what object is created by the library file i.e. from `form-validation`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used the wrong syntax for opps object call.

```
function index(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() ==  FALSE){
    $this->load->view('reg_form_view');//failed input
}else{
    //redirect('reg_success','refresh');
    echo "success";
}
```

Read [formget form validation](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/) and [Codeigniter Form Validation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code it will work`

```
function index(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() ==  FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('reg_form_view');//failed input
    } else {
        //redirect('reg_success','refresh');
        echo "success";
    }
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function index(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() ==  FALSE){
    $this->load->view('reg_form_view');//failed input
}else{
    //redirect('reg_success','refresh');
    echo "success";
}

}
```

Comment: This is wrong. **`form-validation`**